# Browser support for Selectors API

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, css-selectors, selectors-api

Is there a page somewhere which shows the current browser support for the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[When can I use?](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) has a compatibility table for the Selectors API, referring to it by the `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` functions.

Anyway, there is a surprising level of browser support: you'll find that IE8+ and most widely-used versions of other major browsers already implement Selectors API level 1.

Work has begun on [level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2), with features like `find()`, `findAll()` and `matchesSelector()` currently being implemented experimentally.